# Where do I put the console.next( )?

Tags: java, file, graphics, static, console

This code looks through several files to find the popularity and meaning of whatever name you type in. I have barely started the graph part of it so that's why the drawGraph method looks weird. 
I'm wondering how to get it so the user only has to type in the name once. I know having String originalName = console.next(); in the first line of nameToLowerCase is the problem, I just don't know where else to put it. I've tried putting it in the intro but that didn't work because then I would have to make intro equal to the name and whenever I want the name, the whole intro would repeat again.
Thanks, here is my code and output:
Output:

```
This program allows you to search through the
data from the Social Security Administration
to see how popular a particular name has been
since 1890

    Name: aaron
    Aaron f 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 883 0 0 0
    aaron
    aaron
    aaron
    AARON m English, Biblical From the Hebrew name ??????? ('Aharon) which is most likely of unknown Egyptian origin.
    aaron
    aaron
    aaron
    aaron
    aaron
    aaron
    aaron
    aaron
    aaron
    aaron
    aaron
```

(It makes the user type in the name over and over again).
Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BabyNames{ //ADD COMMENTS
   public static final int STARTINGYEAR = 1890;
   public static final int WIDTH = 60;
   public static final int HEIGHT = 30; 
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(780,560);
      Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
      Scanner nameFile = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
      Scanner meaningsFile = new Scanner(new File("meanings.txt"));
      Scanner nameFile2 = new Scanner(new File("names2.txt"));
      intro();
      if(STARTINGYEAR == 1890){
      findingStatistics(console,nameFile);
      drawGraph(g);
      }
      else{
      findingStatistics(console, nameFile2);       
      drawGraph(g);
   }
   findingStatistics(console,meaningsFile);
   }



   public static void intro(){
      System.out.println("This program allows you to search through the");
      System.out.println("data from the Social Security Administration");
      System.out.println("to see how popular a particular name has been");
      System.out.println("since 1890" );
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Name: ");
      }

   public static String nameToLowerCase(Scanner console){   
      String originalName = console.next();
      String name = "" ;
      int lengthOfName = originalName.length();
      String beginingOfName = originalName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
      String endOfName = originalName.substring(1,lengthOfName).toLowerCase();
      name = beginingOfName + endOfName;
      return name;
   }
   public static String findingStatistics(Scanner console, Scanner data){
      String nameFinal = nameToLowerCase(console);
      boolean goesThroughOnce = false; //
      String statistics = "";
      String currWord = "";
      String currLine = "";
      while (data.hasNext() && goesThroughOnce == false){ 
         currLine = data.nextLine();
         Scanner lineBeingRead = new Scanner(currLine); //make other scanners?? for each file
         currWord = lineBeingRead.next(); //

         if (currWord.equals(nameFinal) || currWord.equals(nameFinal.toUpperCase())){   //         
            statistics = currLine;
            goesThroughOnce = true;
            System.out.println(statistics);
        }
        else{
        }
   }
   return statistics;
}
   public static void drawGraph(Graphics g){
   g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
   g.fillRect(0,0,780,30);
   g.fillRect(0,530,780,30);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want that the user has to provide the search term only once.

One solution is a slight refactoring. Just declare the `nameFinal` variable at class level and read the input for that variable once after calling `intro()`.

This would look like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BabyNames{ //ADD COMMENTS
   public static final int STARTINGYEAR = 1890;
   public static final int WIDTH = 60;
   public static final int HEIGHT = 30; 

   // CLASS LEVEL VAR TO HOLD THE SEARCH TERM
   private static String nameFinal;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(780,560);
      Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
      Scanner nameFile = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
      Scanner meaningsFile = new Scanner(new File("meanings.txt"));
      Scanner nameFile2 = new Scanner(new File("names2.txt"));
      intro();

      // READ THE SEARCH HERE ONLY ONCE
      nameFinal = nameToLowerCase(console);

      if(STARTINGYEAR == 1890){
      findingStatistics(console,nameFile);
      drawGraph(g);
      }
      else{
      findingStatistics(console, nameFile2);       
      drawGraph(g);
   }
   findingStatistics(console,meaningsFile);
   }



   public static void intro(){
      System.out.println("This program allows you to search through the");
      System.out.println("data from the Social Security Administration");
      System.out.println("to see how popular a particular name has been");
      System.out.println("since 1890" );
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Name: ");
      }

   public static String nameToLowerCase(Scanner console){   
      String originalName = console.next();
      String name = "" ;
      int lengthOfName = originalName.length();
      String beginingOfName = originalName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
      String endOfName = originalName.substring(1,lengthOfName).toLowerCase();
      name = beginingOfName + endOfName;
      return name;
   }
   public static String findingStatistics(Scanner console, Scanner data){
      // NOW THE nameFinal VAR ALREADY HAS A VALUE
      boolean goesThroughOnce = false; //
      String statistics = "";
      String currWord = "";
      String currLine = "";
      while (data.hasNext() && goesThroughOnce == false){ 
         currLine = data.nextLine();
         Scanner lineBeingRead = new Scanner(currLine); //make other scanners?? for each file
         currWord = lineBeingRead.next(); //

         if (currWord.equals(nameFinal) || currWord.equals(nameFinal.toUpperCase())){   //         
            statistics = currLine;
            goesThroughOnce = true;
            System.out.println(statistics);
        }
        else{
        }
   }
   return statistics;
}
   public static void drawGraph(Graphics g){
   g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
   g.fillRect(0,0,780,30);
   g.fillRect(0,530,780,30);
  }
}
```

Comment: What am I supposed to add in as "// READ THE SEARCH HERE ONLY ONCE"?

Comment: Nothing, the comment is explaining what happens in the next line.

Comment: I'm a beginner and is what you added called an "array"? I'm not allowed to use them in this assignment and I don't know what they are.

Comment: No, this isn't an array. It is just a variable at class level (instead of beeing at method level like you had it before).

Comment: You should accept the answer if it solved the problem to show that the question was answered.